# Data type mismatch in VBA when filtering form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, filter, ms-access-2016

I have a form with textboxes and one combobox which has the order number, and one command to print the form as PDF and save it to specific folder and then attach it to the attachment column on the same orders table with the same order number selected from my combobox

I made this code below but I am facing this issue

**

**It is working and saving PDF file now, but how can I manage to attach the same file to the attachment field in the same table with the same order number row?**
I tried the following code to attach but it is not finding the record by Order number

```html
Private Sub Command8_Click()

Dim FileName As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim attachFld As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, rsAtt As DAO.Recordset2

FileName = Me.Order_Number
filepath = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Newfolder\" & FileName & ".pdf"
Forms("Receipt").Filter = "[Order]=" & Me![Order] & ""
Forms("Receipt").FilterOn = True
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "Receipt", acFormatPDF, filepath
'DoCmd.Save acForm, "Receipt"
'DoCmd.Close acForm, "Receipt", acSaveNo

' to SAVE ATTACHMENT

'Dim fPath As String: fPath = "C:\Users\india\Desktop\New folder (2)\New folder\"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("WorkOrders")

    If Dir(filepath & rs.Fields("Order").value & ".pdf") <> "" Then
    
        rs.Edit
        Set rsAtt = rs.Fields("Attachment").value
        With rsAtt
            .AddNew
            .Fields("Attachment").LoadFromFile (filepath & rs.Fields("ID").value & ".pdf")
            .Update
        End With
        rs.Update
    End If






End Sub
```

**

```html
Private Sub Command8_Click()
Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePatch As String
FileName = "Order_No_" & Me.Order_Number
Filepath = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Newfolder" & FileName & ".pdf"
Forms("Receipt").Filter = "[Order]='" & Me![Order] & "'"
Forms("Receipt").FilterOn = True
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "Receipt", acFormatPDF, Filepath
'DoCmd.Save acForm, "Receipt"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Receipt", acSaveNo
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is order a numeric field?  May not need the `'`s

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes it is

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I removed the ' and it works fine but not saving the PDF file to my pc !!

Comment: @ALeXceL ohh, whta should I do in this case I am new to this please

Comment: You didn't put "Option Explicit" at the beginning of the module. So the misspelling passes: FilePatch X FilePath. In "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Newfolder" & FileName & ".pdf" you must put a "\" after 'Newfolder' avoiding concatenation of the filename with the file path. I did not check the code itself (MsAccess?).

Comment: 'Option Explicit' <- always place it at the beginning of the module. This avoids missing DIMs and etc... So, the moment you just type "FilePath" the VBE will alert you about the error when typing the DIMmed "FilePatch". You can configure it automatically: in VBE>Tools>Options>Require variable declaration. In that same dialog box, uncheck "Auto Syntax Check" avoiding the annoying alerts emitted by the VBE in the form of MsgBoxes.

Comment: @ALeXceL it works now after I added "\", but I did not get the order number saved after the name FileName = "Order_No_" & Me.Order_Number this is what I got after saving Order_No_1.pdf

Comment: Forms("Receipt").Filter = "[Order]='" & Me![Order] & "'" <<< is this all correct? Probably mistake on the field name?

Comment: yes it is all ok, and how can I now attach the same PDF file to the same order number as attachment? @ALeXceL

Comment: Open a new question - this one should be closed as it was basically all typo errors